# Set scroll to one of the MenuItem on a contextmenu in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, contextmenu

I have a context menu, and it had a few items.
Like always if scroll over one of the items I can see the sub-items in that menu.

But its size is very huge I can't able to see the full lists or scroll it.

Since the sub-items are loaded dynamically I use like :

```
<ContextMenu >
  <MenuItem Header="Mobiles" ItemSource={Binding...}>
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Stryle targeyType="MenuItem"> 
       <Setter property="HeaderTemplate">
       <Setter.Value> 
         <DataTemplate> <TextBlock Text ="{Binding MobilName}"/> </DataTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
         <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ViewMobileCommand}"/>
        </Setter >
      </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
  </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu >
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to tackle this?

Comment: It's not usual UI design to have a very long list of options in a menu.  Mobiles. That's a list of many mobile phones? Hundreds maybe. This seems like something which would be more appropriate in the main window rather than as a set of menu items, Maybe in a treeview or listbox. With a filter of some sort if there are more than a few window height's worth.

Comment: @Andy, actually  'Mobile' is just a hypothetical example I used, since I can't share my original code/bindings.

Comment: @Andy  In my use-case,  this 'ContextMenu' is on a 'row' > 'particular column', so a treeview or Listbox is out of scope.  Everything works fine to me, but the items in the 'Menu' is more than 100  which exceeded the screen size. so Just i need a scroll-view or some other mechanism